# check if string variable name is a javascript fuction of an object

Tags: javascript, function, callback, javascript-objects, callable-object

How to check if the string parameter passed in a function is too callable/function but not directly under `window.`.

I know the open/ directly callable function can be checked using the syntax `window['functionName']`

But how about the member function declared inside an object to be checked?

In below example `openFunction()` can be called but how to call `obj1.foo()`?

> Prefer not to use `eval()`

### Example Code:

```js
var obj1 = {
  foo: function() {
    alert("I'm a function");
  }
}

function openFunction() {
  alert("I know i am easily callable");
}

function callSomeone(txtcallback) {
  var fn = window[txtcallback];
  if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    fn();
  }
  console.log(typeof fn);
}

callSomeone('openFunction'); //function
callSomeone('obj1.foo'); //undefined
```

Comment: You should take a look to JsonPath. It uses a kind of `XPath` for "querying" objects => http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns `undefined` because, your code is equivalent to `window["obj1.foo"]` which is not correct.

The correct way to access to `foo` function is `window["obj1"]["foo"]`.

So you have to "cycle" through the string `obj1.foo`.

Here I added a `GetProp` function that do that cycle and is recursive, so the level of nesting is not a problem.

```js
var obj1 = {
  foo: function() {
    alert("I'm a function");
  }
}

function openFunction() {
  alert("I know i am easily callable");
}

function callSomeone(txtcallback) {
  var fn = GetProp(window, txtcallback.split("."));
  if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    fn();
  }
  console.log(typeof fn);
}

function GetProp(obj, props) {
  if(props.length == 0) {
    return obj;
  } else if(obj[props[0]] != undefined) {
    obj = obj[props[0]];
    return GetProp(obj, props.slice(1));
  }
}

callSomeone('openFunction'); //function
callSomeone('obj1.foo'); //undefined
```

Comment: Thanks, i found yours is most professional way of coding solution.

Comment: i have extended question on this. if i wants to maintain an index (id) variable/member of the object. calling such way it getting lost it's value.

`var obj1 = {
 id: 0,
  foo: function() {
   ++this.id;
    alert("id = " + this.id);
  }
}`

Comment: In this case, try JsonPath. It should work for your need.

Comment: replacing `this.id` with `this.obj1.id` or `window.obj1.id` works. (what is the difference if you can explain.) but why not the syntax according to JsonPath tutorial works `$.obj.id` works?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var obj1 = {
  foo: function() {
    alert("I'm a function");
  }
}

function openFunction() {
  alert("I know i am easily callable");
}

function callSomeone(txtcallback) {
    str =txtcallback.split(".");
    temp = window;
    for(check in str){
        temp = temp[str[check]];
         if (typeof temp === 'function') {
            temp();
            break;
         }else if(typeof temp === 'undefined'){
             break;
         }
    }
  console.log(typeof temp);
}

callSomeone('openFunction'); //function
callSomeone('obj1.foo'); //function
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ant to look for members inside nested maps you have to use a recursive approach.

```
function callSomeone(txtcallback) {
  var keyPath = txtcallback.split(".");
  var fn = keyPath.reduce(function (member, key) {
    return member[key];
  }, window);

  if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    fn();
  }
  console.log(typeof fn);
}
```

the downside in this example is that the function is executed in the global scope. If you need to keep the scope of the container object you need to also save the scope.

```
var obj1 = {
  foo: function() {
    alert("I'm a function");
    return this;
  }
}

function openFunction() {
  alert("I know i am easily callable");
  return this;
}

function callSomeone(txtcallback) {
  var keyPath = txtcallback.split(".");

  var scope = null;

  var context = null;
  var fn = keyPath.reduce(function (member, key) {
    scope = member;
    return member[key];
  }, window);

  if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    context = fn.call(scope);
  }
  console.log(typeof fn, context);
}

callSomeone('openFunction'); //function
callSomeone('obj1.foo'); //undefined
```

Comment: Normally I would use a library such as lodash to accomplish this. This is merely showing how it could work. In lodash I would probably use `_.result`. https://lodash.com/docs#result